# Hose Y-connector to join hot and cold?

Tags: hose

I want to combine water from a hot and cold spigot to a single hose. What is the fitting called that does this?

The fittings I have seen only split a single water source into two different branches, not the other way around.

Comment: if you reverse it it will do what you want

Comment: Turn it upside down.  They work both ways.  Might need hose and/or adapters to make it fit.

Comment: Do you want to achieve a certain temperature of the combined hot and cold streams? Or would you just accept whatever temperature results from the two streams? A standard faucet with mixing chamber combines hot and cold in whatever proportions the user wants.

Comment: Do check that what you are trying to do is legal in your country.  Because in mine, mixing hot and cold in that manner would be illegal unless the cold water was coming from your own tank.

Comment: @SimonB  Can you expand on your comment.  Because this is what happens in every sink faucet/tap, except as a tee instead of a Y.

Comment: A hose splitter valve.  Example image from eBay: https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/nMIAAOSwAfpj5ojo/s-l500.jpg

Comment: @crip659 Here in the UK, there are rules to prevent accidentally back-feeding your hot water into the public water supply.  All the mixer taps in my house have concentric pipes in the spout,  The hot and cold water doesn't actually mix until it has left the tap.  An alternative would be a one-way valve to prevent backfeeding.

Comment: @SimonB   This why location matters on this site.  Standards/regulations can be different from country to country.

Comment: @SimonB Amazing that UK fixtures have no internal mixing but in the US internal mixing inside a chamber in the valve body is the norm. However, even in the UK aren't the streams mixed inside tubing in the shower plumbing? Sixty years ago I worked in an instutional scullery where the hot water was at higher pressure than the cold water. If one was not careful with the valve settings on some faucets, hot water would travel back through the cold water line.

Answer (score 4):

Conceptually, as noted in another answer, this is simply a Y in reverse. The problem is that you normally want to control how much hot and how much cold. My old washing machine three temperature settings (with various combinations of them for wash vs. rinse):

- Hot = 100% hot
- Cold = 100% cold
- Warm = 100% hot + 100% cold

The warm isn't mixing in the pipe or valve. It simply opens up both hot and cold valves at the same time and they both pour into the tub. What temperature is that water? If the pressure is the same (it *should* be the same, but due to a water heater in the middle on the hot supply, they might not be *exactly* the same), that could be many different things:

- 40F + 120F = 80F
- 40F + 140F = 90F
- 60F + 120F = 90F
- 60F + 140F = 100F

etc.

For typical clothes washing, it doesn't usually matter much. For other things, it might matter a lot. Which is why faucets (kitchen, bath, laundry, etc.) either have separate hot and cold handles or a single handle that adjusts the mixture of hot and cold. And for automated things where the temperature matters, either the device will have a thermostat to control the mixing, a way to stop it from getting *too* hot or a way to heat it up if it is too cold (e.g., for a dishwasher).

There is an additional complication with the described situation, which is that you need to have some sort of check valve or backflow preventer to make sure that you don't get flow from the cold line into the hot line or vice versa. That isn't a problem normally with a faucet or washing machine but could be with a hose attached as described.

But in the end, if you really want to have an arbitrary setting (not adapting based on incoming water temperatures), yes such devices exist. In a quick search, I found as one example [this model from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/SLOAN-Mix60A-3326009-Optima-Faucet-Mixer-Below-Deck-Mechanical-Water-Mixing-Valve-Polished-Chrome-683100/206050660):

[image: mixing valve]

It has 3 connections - hot inlet, cold inlet, mixed outlet. It has check valves on the hot and cold inlets. It is adjustable, so you can do something other than an exact 50/50.

Come to think of it, based on some Q&A on the Home Depot page, this type of thing may be how public bathrooms set the temperature for automatic faucets. I never thought about it before, but they can't do pure cold because people would complain, and they can't do pure hot because it would be too hot. This is how you get to the goldilocks temperature. But not perfect - which makes sense because it is just a simple setting and not a real thermostatic mixing.

Comment: Unless you have one of those **magical Y** splitter with two valves on it where you can control how much you mix of each and that way control the temperature

Answer (score 0):

All of the following do what you want

They are either one in and 2 out

or if you reveres the connection then it is two in and one out.

Additionally they have independent **flow valves** so you can control the mixing of hot and cold.

[image: y splitter]

There are adapters for Male/Female and Female/Male

Comment: you cannot revers the connection. The inlet is female and the outlets are male.

Comment: @RMDman did you hear there are adapters for that

Comment: That info was not in your answer. the Y is plentiful most anywhere, even grocery stores, but I have not seen an adapter yet.

Comment: @RMDman I newer go to grocery store for my plumbing needs, do you ?

Comment: Adapters should be available in any garden supply shop and most hardware stores, plus home centers which have some of both. It's still not a great solution; see the answer by _manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact_ for details of why and how to avoid those issues
.

Comment: @Ruskes,  I don't go to the grocery store for plumbing need, but doesn't change the fact that the Y  can be purchased there...and if so, still doesn't help with the OPs issue.